# Setting priors in MCMCglmm in a multi-response model

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I need to create a `multiple regression model` to estimate the potential 'defense' that a plant would have given their size and genetic family. I tried to use `MCMCglmm` to adjust this model.

I have data regarding three defensive traits (HCN, DT, and NEF) from plants in an experimental plot in the field.

```
HCN -> cyanide content (mg of HCN per g of tissue)

DT -> trichome density (trichomes per mm2)

NEF -> sugar content in extrafloral nectar in mg
```

I also measured size traits on those same plants when I measured the defensive traits. Size traits are basal diameter (DB) and plant height (Alt). I wanna try make model with each of them and choose the one that fits better.

The full model that I have adjusted is

```
cbind(HCN,DT,NEF) ~ trait:DB + trait:Fam -1, random = ~ us(trait):Cuadro, 
rcov=~ us(trait):units,family = rep("gaussian", 2), prior=priors, nitt = 60000, 
burnin = 10000, thin=50, data = Base
```

- I use `trait:Fam` and `trait:DB` because I want to have different
  regression slopes per genetic family.
- I also add the `-1` in the formula to omit the overall intercept.
- For the random I use `us(trait):Cuadro` because allows for covariance
  across traits for the family.
- I use gaussian for the three `defense` variables.

When I run the model, I use the priors suggested in 
*Hadfield 2010*

```
priors <- list(R = list(V = diag(2)/3, n = 2), G = list(G1 = list(
               V = diag(2)/3, n = 2), G2 = list(V = diag(2)/3, n = 2)))
```

But I get an error of having the wrong number of G structures, and I don't know how to adjust the prior to my model that have three response variables.

Comment: welcome to SO. have a look [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make a good reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As a test, can you simplify the model such that the error does not occur?